# searching for WMS for canada weather

Tags: weather, canada

I need WMS server links for

- metar
- radar
- satelite

I have Environnement Canada but there's no metar

Comment: I'm trying to keep it live on a map (QGIS)

Comment: Does http://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/2676/obtaining-hourly-weather-data-including-direct-and-diffuse-insolation help?

Comment: [GeoMet](http://www.ec.gc.ca/meteo-weather/default.asp?lang=En&amp;n=C0D9B3D8-1 "GeoMet") doesn't seem to do METAR. Nav Canada seems to manage most METAR reporting, but has no WMS I know if.